# Why git asks for username when ran inside a script?

Tags: git, github

I have a `Push` command, that runs this script:

```
FindGits |
{
    while read gitFolder; do
        parent=$(dirname $gitFolder);
        if [[ `git -C $parent status --porcelain` ]]; then
            echo;
            (
                echo $parent;
                git -C $parent status --porcelain
                git -C $parent add .
                git -C $parent commit -m "committed by script" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
                if [[ $? == 128 ]]; then
                    git -C $parent commit -m "commited by script" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
                    git -C $parent push
                    if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then
                        git -C $parent pull
                        git -C $parent push
                    fi
                else 
                    git -C $parent push
                    if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then
                        git -C $parent pull
                        git -C $parent push
                    fi
                fi
            ) &
        fi
    done
    wait
}
```

However, when I run it, git asks for username:

> Username for 'https://github.com':

Here are the tests I have done, to make sure git has access to GitHub:

- `ssh -T git@github.com` => successful
- `sudo -i` + `ssh -T git@github.com` => successful
- I go into a git repository, and I change something, and I manaully add + commit + push => successful
- I go to my home, and add + commit + push from another repository using `-C another_git_repo_path` => successfull

Then why it does not work when I run it from inside a script?

Comment: Do all your git repositories use the `ssh` method? For example, all of them  have in `.git/config` something like: `url = git@github.com:....` instead of `url = https://github.com/...`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, that was exactly the point. Thank you. Please send your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ssh` authentication for working with git repositories (and make `pull`,`push`, etc.) you have to config every repository to use `ssh` authentication instead of `https`, otherwise the git command will keep asking for your user and password.

For changing the repository authentication to `ssh` you can use something like:

1. `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:UserName/Repo.git`
2. Or in `.git/config` file you can change he line `url = https://github.com/` to `url = git@github.com:....`:

```
$> cat .git/config

[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:UserName/Repo.git # edited line
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```